# Argument of type 'string | Date' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Date'

Tags: javascript, typescript, jestjs

Im trying to write a test suite by mocking date. I get this error 'Argument of type 'string | Date' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Date'.'. Here is the function

```
const getDay = (inputDate: any, today = new Date()) => {
  const reportDate = new Date(inputDate)
  if (today >= reportDate) {
    const differenceInTime = today.getTime() - reportDate.getTime()
    const differenceInDays = differenceInTime / (1000 * 3600 * 24)
    const finalDayDiff = Math.floor(differenceInDays)
    if (finalDayDiff === 0) {
      return translate("common.today")
    } else if (finalDayDiff === 1) {
      return finalDayDiff + translate("common.dayAgo")
    } else {
      return finalDayDiff + translate("common.daysAgo")
    }
  } else {
    return ""
  }
}
```

and the failing test suite, the testName and todayDate get highlighted in red

```
import { getDay } from "../common-functions"
import { translate } from "../../i18n/translate"

describe("checkForDifferenceInDays", () => {
  Array.of(
    [
      "1. difference in days - 1 day ago",
      new Date("2021-03-18T00:00:00.000Z"),
      1 + translate("common.dayAgo"),
    ],
    [
      "2. difference in days - 5 day ago",
      new Date("2021-03-22T00:00:00.000Z"),
      5 + translate("common.daysAgo"),
    ],
    [
      "3. difference in days - today",
      new Date("2021-03-17T00:00:00.000Z"),
      translate("common.today"),
    ],
    ["4. empty string", new Date("2021-03-15T00:00:00.000Z"), ""],
  ).forEach((testCase) => {
    const [testName, todayDate, expectedResult] = testCase
    const reportDate = "2021-03-17T00:00:00.000Z"
    test(**testName**, () => {
      //Act
      const actualResult = getDay(reportDate, **todayDate**)
      //Assert
      expect(actualResult).toEqual(expectedResult)
    })
  })
})
Highlighted in bold shows an error. can someone help what i am missing
```

Answer (score 1):

This is mixed array with `Array<string | Date>` type:

```
[
  "1. difference in days - 1 day ago",
  new Date("2021-03-18T00:00:00.000Z"),
  1 + translate("common.dayAgo"),
],
```

And `Array.of` is unnecessary here. In order for array elements to have precise types, it should be a constant:

```
  ([
    [
      "1. difference in days - 1 day ago",
      new Date("2021-03-18T00:00:00.000Z"),
      1 + translate("common.dayAgo"),
    ],
    ...
  ] as const).forEach(...)
```

Answer (score 1):

Your testcase currently works on an array of arrays, and each of the inner arrays holds elements of type `string` or `Date`. (This can be explicitly expressed in TypeScript as type `(string | Date)[][]` or `Array<Array<string | Date>>`.)

You could try to use an array of *tuples* instead of an array of arrays here. (This can be explicitly expressed in TypeScript as type `[string, Date, string][]` or `Array<[string, Date, string]>`.) Tuple elements are more explicitly typed, so this may work correctly when destructuring the elements inside your `forEach` callback function.

For more clarity I refactored your code a little. I hope you don't mind.

```ts
import { getDay } from "../common-functions"
import { translate } from "../../i18n/translate"

describe("checkForDifferenceInDays", () => {
  const arr: [string, Date, string][] =
    [
      [
        "1. difference in days - 1 day ago",
        new Date("2021-03-18T00:00:00.000Z"),
        1 + translate("common.dayAgo")
      ],
      [
        "2. difference in days - 5 day ago",
        new Date("2021-03-22T00:00:00.000Z"),
        5 + translate("common.daysAgo"),
      ],
      [
        "3. difference in days - today",
        new Date("2021-03-17T00:00:00.000Z"),
        translate("common.today"),
      ],
      [
        "4. empty string",
        new Date("2021-03-15T00:00:00.000Z"),
        ""
      ]
    ]

  arr.forEach((testCase) => {
    const [testName, todayDate, expectedResult] = testCase
    const reportDate = "2021-03-17T00:00:00.000Z"
    test(testName, () => {
      //Act
      const actualResult = getDay(reportDate, todayDate)
      //Assert
      expect(actualResult).toEqual(expectedResult)
    })
  })
})
```